# How to avoid repetition of value in combobox?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have two combo box, When I have to choose "Mary Ver Pamposa" in first combobox, it's still shows "Mary Ver Pamposa" in the second combo box. How can avoid this one, when I'm going to choose the value and not show in second combo box? any example? I can't post my sample image here due to reputations I have.

```
<div class="governor">
    <div class="gov-margin">
        <?php 
            $governor=mysql_query("select * from candidate where Position='Governor'")or die(mysql_error());
            while($row=mysql_fetch_array($governor)){ $governor_id=$row['CandidateID'];
        ?>

            <img class="gov" src="<?php echo $row['Photo'];?>" width="150" height="150" border="0" onmouseover="showtrail('<?php echo $row['Photo'];?>','<?php echo $row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName'];?> ',200,5)" onmouseout="hidetrail()">
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;

        <?php } ?>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="select_gov">
    <div class="margin-gov">
        <select name="governor" class="span222">
            <option class="option">--Select Candidate--</option>
            <?php
                $governor=mysql_query("select * from candidate where Position='Governor'")or die(mysql_error());
                while($row=mysql_fetch_array($governor)){ $governor_id=$row['CandidateID'];
            ?>

                <option value="<?php echo $governor_id; ?>" class="option"><?php  echo $row['FirstName']." ".$row['LastName']; ?></option>

            <?php } ?>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Only one select box shown and a set of corresponding images. Why do you need 2 queries for the same data?

Comment: Where are the second combobox ?